# How do I add an attribute to the field of the base class from child class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, custom-attributes

**Base class:**

```
public class XmlNameValueField : XmlBaseField
{                       
        [XmlAttribute("n")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }        
 }
```

**Child Class:**

```
 public class DateField : XmlNameValueField
 {            
 }
```

In the Child class field Name must have an additional attribute

```
[DataType (DataType.EmailAddress)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to mark the property as virtual in the base class, override it in the child class and add the attributes.

Comment: if the base class has a definition, wouldn't the child class override that definition?

Comment: @sksallaj, attributes can be inherited (using the AttributeUsageAttribute attribute on the attribute itself)

Comment: and what about the method implementation? What if the guy wanted to keep the implementation in the base class and not override it in the child? But append the attribute only for the child?

Comment: @sksallaj sorry I don't undersand what you mean, which method are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry about that. Okay so if a base class has a method called "Add(int x, int y)" And the method implementation is "return x+y", if the child wants to add an attribute that the parent does not have, but not override what the parent does "return x+y", this solution wouldn't work?

Comment: If it's virtual, you could override it and call base.Add(x, y) but adding the attribute to the child implementation would probably change the class's semantic violating the Liskov substitution principle