# Adding attributes to a derived type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework).  I have a partial class called Company that is generated by EF.  The partial class looks like:

> The type 'BaseModels.Company' already contains a definition for 'CompanyName'"

```
public partial class Company {
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is create a derived class from Company that has an extra property.

```
public class MyCompany : Company {
    public string UploadName { get; set; }
}
```

But I want to decorate the base type property CompanyName with a custom attribute.

I went to the following location:
[How do I add an attribute to the field of the base class from child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851069/how-do-i-add-an-attribute-to-the-field-of-the-base-class-from-child-class?rq=1)

Which does answer my question.  The problem is if I marked the CompanyName property in the base class as "virtual", then EF could regenerate the code which would override my stuff.

I tried to define a partial class, but VS 2013 complained when I tried to add:

```
public partial class Company {
    [Renderer("html")]
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

by stating that the property name already existed.

How would I get around this hurdle?

Comment: `what does VS2013 complain about???`.. also where are you overriding it in the child class..?

Comment: The error message that is generated from Visual Studio says the "The type 'BaseModels.Company' already contains a definition for 'CompanyName'".  This is from a partial class I tried to define in the same project.

Comment: is this EF Database First..? if so here is a link to read step-by-step http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021991/entity-framework-database-first-how-to-alter-entities-to-make-them-derive-from-a

Comment: There's not a way to add an attribute to non-virtual base members from a derived type.  And you can't use `partial` to _change_ members, only to _add_ members.  I would just bite the bullet and use different types.  Use the entity types _just_ for manipulating data, and map them to your "domain" types that you can decorate however you want.  Tools like AutoMapper make it pretty painless unless you want to do some weird mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot with partial class define property that already exists. You add attribute over existing property you need to use MetadataTypeAttribute. Create partial class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CompanyMetadata))]
public partial class Company { }
```

and add metadata class to your project with your property with desired attribute:

```
public class CompanyMetadata
{
    [Renderer("html")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Company an abstract class. Then use override keyword with CompanyName to add the custom attribute. You can also add UploadName.

Comment: But the Company class is generated by the Entity Framework.  I'm not sure how that will solve the problem.